# PHP Background Processing Script is not working on Server

Tags: php, laravel-5, background-process

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` in my localhost the background script works perfectly fine but when i upload script to server and try to run it. It doesn't work.

Below is the script

```
<?php
                   public function test1(Request $request) {
                      ob_start();
                      ignore_user_abort(true);

                      echo json_encode([]);

                      header("Connection: close");
                      header("Content-Length:" . (string) ob_get_length());

                      ob_flush();
                      ob_end_clean();
                      ob_implicit_flush(true);
                      ob_end_flush();
                      
                      for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++){
                              Log::info($i);
                      }
                  } ?>
```

IN LOCAL PC I USE `WINDOWS OS, XAMP` AND ON SERVER `Linux`

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: It doesn't work how? What error messages and/or error logs? What's the expected result and what are you getting? Please give the "How to Ask" section a good read and edit your question to meet SO's standards.

Comment: @Javier Larroulet the script works but the difference is in local pc it redirects to other page and the process will still be present in background.                                              But on Server it Completes the task and then redirect to given URL. Now what is wanted is first it should redirect to other URL but the work in this case `for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++){
                              Log::info($i);
                      }`  must be running in background.

Comment: @PavanWebbeez What are the PHP versions (local and remote)? Which web servers?

Comment: @D.Go on it is 7.2.12 on local and on 7.2.6 server

Comment: @PavanWebbeez And which web servers?

Comment: @D.Go `Linux x86_64`

Comment: @PavanWebbeez You are not answering my question. I'm not asking which OS. I am asking which web servers are running on your local computer and the remote server. For example, if you're using Apache on the remote server, it may handle things differently.

Comment: @D.Go Apache webserver on local and online

Comment: Okay. Please also provide a [mcve]. Your example above is an incomplete function.

Comment: @D.Go I have provided the best information possible.

Comment: @PavanWebbeez No. This script does nothing and is missing the PHP terminator - `?>`.

Comment: I have updated now

Comment: @PavanWebbeez When and how does `test1()` get called?